# Capture video in mp4 format using intent - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, video

So I have been searching for the solution from past few days but it seems that I am unable to find any. At first it seems simple enough.

I have an app that uses default Android camera app to capture the video using intent. Video recording is working perfect but the file format is 3gp. I want to record the video in mp4 format but I do not want to implement my own `mediarecorder` etc to build my own video recording module.

I have also searched for available extra parameters I can pass into the intent for the file format but I couldn't.

Is there any extra parameter that I can use for selecting file format?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
// Use this code to capture Mp4 video. 

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    private Camera myCamera;
    private CameraSurfaceView cameraSurfaceView;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

    Button myButton;
    boolean recording;
    public Context context;
    private Uri fileUri;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        recording = false;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Get Camera for preview
        myCamera = getCameraInstance();
        if(myCamera == null){
            Log.w(TAG, "camera not found");
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "Fail to get Camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        cameraSurfaceView = new CameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera);
        FrameLayout cameraPreview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        cameraPreview.addView(cameraSurfaceView);

        myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);

    }

    Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener
            = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try{
                if(recording){
                    // stop recording and release camera
                    mediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                    releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object

                    //Exit after saved
                    //finish();
                    myButton.setText("REC");
                    recording = false;
                    Log.e("file path",fileUri.getPath());


                }else{

                    //Release Camera before MediaRecorder start
                    releaseCamera();

                    if(!prepareMediaRecorder()){
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }

                    mediaRecorder.start();
                    recording = true;
                    myButton.setText("STOP");
                    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Timer timer = new Timer();
                            timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 10000);
                        }
                    };
                    handler.postDelayed(r, 10000);

                }
            }catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };

    private Camera getCameraInstance(){

        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT); // attempt to get a Camera instance
            c.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if(recording ==true) {
                            recording = false;
                            Log.e("file path",fileUri.getPath());

                            doAsynchronousTask.cancel();
                        } else{
                            doAsynchronousTask.cancel();
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };


    private boolean prepareMediaRecorder(){
        myCamera = getCameraInstance();

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        myCamera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(fileUri.getPath());


        //mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo1.mp4");
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(10000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
        mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Set max file size 50M

        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(cameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());


        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();


        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
        releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
            mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            myCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
        if (myCamera != null){
            myCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            myCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public class CameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;

        public CameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            mCamera = camera;

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int weight,
                                   int height) {
            // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
            // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
                // preview surface does not exist
                return;
            }

            // stop preview before making changes
            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
                // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
            }

            // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

            // start preview with new settings
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();

            } catch (Exception e){
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /**
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }



}
```

Comment: Is there a way to force native camera app by specifying some extra parameters for mp4 fornat? I don't want to implement my own video recording module.

Comment: Please try that code, by using that code you just start native camera in your app and click a button it start your recording. It record video in mp4 format.